# Conditional format cells of the form x ± y

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, conditional-formatting

I have a 1 million numbers as cells that are in the form "3.1415926 ± 2.731828." and 314±27 and 314 ± 27.32

I want to conditional format or in general format those cells so that they only have 4 figures after the decimal point.

In other words,

"3.1415926 ± 2.731828." becomes "3.142 ± 2.732" etc.

I also have some cells with numbers including 319 ± 283. I want to keep the values in those cells the same.

How do I achieve this desired result in excel?

Comment: Select the cells, right-click on one of them, select **Format Cells**, select **Number**, and type 4 in the **Decimal places**.

Comment: The problem is I have 30,000 cells and I want to automate this.

Comment: If they're all adjacent, selecting them in Excel takes literally a couple of seconds. Way much faster than even thinking of how to automate that. Conditional formatting still requires selecting the cells, so you're only option of automating this without selecting the cells is writing a VBA script.

Comment: @RacilHilan The problem is since I have # ± #. Excel no longer reads this as a number and I can't change sig figs.

Comment: *I have a 1 million numbers as cells that are in the form "3.1415926 ± 2.731828."* This value cannot have a number datatype! it is a string. So no number format can be applied to it without data value change (and loose the tail). So you may re-format this string into a string of the format you need assigning the resulted value to another cell only. And I agree that VBA function is the simplest way to do this (or VBA macro to perform this in-place by request overwriting source values).

Comment: Perhaps you could export to another spreadsheet program, use RegEx to Find/Replace, and import back to Excel. Of course, that would result in the `3.1415926 ± 2.731828` being saved in the sheet as `3.1415 ± 2.7318`. Notice the lack of rounding as well.

Comment: How about splitting the value first and then only keep 4 figures for number and then re-join these field?

Comment: OK, I see now what you mean. Still the steps are almost the same except, instead of applying the generic number format, you'd apply a formula. The formula will split the two numbers, format them and then join them again putting back the symbol between them. You put all that in a function, select all the cells that require it, and apply the function to them. It is pretty easy to do, but you'll have to write the code in VBA. Start writing the code, and if you face some issues, post it in your question so we can help you.

Comment: @Lee I'd do that but 329 becomes 329.0000 which is a thing I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with formatting since number formatting will not apply to a string.  You will need to use formulas (or VBA) to change the display.

Also note that, unlike with formatting, the result value will not be the same as the original value.

- Split the string
- Round each segment
- Reassemble the number

---

```
=ROUND(LEFT(A1,FIND("±",A1)-1),3) & " ± " & ROUND(MID(A1,FIND("±",A1)+1,99),3)
```

Note that this method will drop any trailing zero's after the rounding. I have no idea if that is what you want. But it works for your examples.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is that there is a third way to format cell contents. You can use it since you are willing to split the content and put it back together.

Normal formatting through the `Ctrl-1` dialogue box is method 1 and it cannot handle this. Method 2 is the condifitional formatting functionality and it would be a stone cold $@#&% to do it there. Method 3 can do this and also let you format things like 20 value level formats if you like. (The kind of thing where if the value is between 1 and 10 it gets one format, between 10 and 100 it gets a different one:  normal formatting limits you to four of these conditions).

So, split the values into two individual numbers, and format each one by using the `TEXT()` function to set the format. To get four decimal places if it is not an integer, and no decimal places at all if it is an integer, use an `IF()` test to see if it is an integer and give the resulting `TEXT()` function the format you desire for integers, and if it fails that test, use a `TEXT()` function that gives it four decimal places (or three since you show three in your examples).

Then put those back together. Finally, to use just one helper column, merge the formulas so one formula creates both parts and merges them into the sstring you need. Your end result is text regardless of what you do so forcing the pieces to be text and combining them to be text is no problem.

That `IF()` testing and using different outputs is how you can get the 20, 30, 100, or whatever different value level formats, by the way.

For regular use, like the value level formatting I keep mentioning, the fact that they end up textual, not numerical, is not a problem if you remember one thing:  Excel will treat them as numbers for almost any function meant to do math on numbers but as text for (mostly) functions that are lookups in nature. So doing those in which Excel will fail if given a number to look up in a set of text entries, one can wrap the lookup number value in the same `TEXT()` formatting the data to perform the lookup has. Easy, if remembered. Hard on one if not remembered.

Some oddities in that though. Add two number characters formatted as text and Excel does that, but changes the display formatting of your formula cell to be text too. Even though it performs the addition. Not just displayed either. Use `F2-Enter` and the cell is acted upon as text so it shows the formula not the result. `SUM()` never does the addition to begin with, starting with 0 for a result.

Moral of the quirks in it story:  this is good for values you will not act upon further. Not planning to "math" them at some point, or try to graph them. If you plan lookups using that column, you plan for the quirk. As an output column it's fine. Last concern, really, is that the normal formatting in the cells these will end up in will be changed to TEXT so the column could get a mix of that and whatever it was originally set for. Shouldn't be a big issue of course, because you wouldn't be changing formulas there, not much. Change the value in an input cell and the formula will faithfully recalculate eeven though it has text formatting now. (Go figure, right?)